# Passing React Component as a Prop

Tags: reactjs

In my main component, I have have an array of components that I pass to a child component (in a route) as a prop (this.state.commonProps.leftNavItems).  When I navigate to the child's route and the child component renders, I noticed that the components passed to it as a prop are not the same instances but are instead rendered as new components (new componentDidMount) using their default values (not the current state as exist in the parent). Is there a way to pass the component instances themselves and keep their state, or can you only pass the component definitions and so would end up mounting brand new components when you pass them as props to children?

```
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      render={props => (
        <Layout
          leftNavItems={this.state.commonProps.leftNavItems}
          /* mainItems={simulationRunRequestsMainItems} */
          mainItems={null}
        />
      )}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/simulation-runs"
      render={props => (
        <div>
          <SimulationRun
            commonProps={this.state.commonProps}
            refreshSimulationRuns={this.refreshSimulationRuns}
          />
        </div>
      )}
```

Comment: You normally would pass your items like <Layout><LeftNavItems /></Layout> and can use this.children on your component - what you are doing seems a bit weird.

Comment: @turtlepick, as far as you know, passing a component as a child would result in that specific child instance being passed and maintaining the same state as exists elsewhere in the app?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? What is the value of `this.state.commonProps.leftNavItems`, and in your <Layout /> component, how do you render `leftNavItems`?